# C# Exception, can't add to ADO.Net Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a problem, the program launches but it crashes with an exception :
 Message=Invalid object name 'dbo.Entity1Set'.
What happens ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Model1Container db = new Model1Container();
        db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        Personne ps = new Personne();
        ps.Nom = "Loup";
        ps.Prénom = "Julien";
        db.PersonneSet.Add(ps);
        db.GetValidationErrors();
        db.SaveChanges(); //Exception ???
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I don't know how and where to add "CreateDatabaseIfNotExists" in my code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Exception: Invalid object name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581147/entity-framework-exception-invalid-object-name).  Please make sure you've set `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`

Comment: ok but I don't know where and how to add CreateDatabaseIfNotExists in my code, exactly

Comment: Any idea to help me ? If the problem is to ad d "CreateDatabaseIfNotExists", I edited my first message