# Entity Framework code first - isn't it meant to create tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dnx

After *MUCH* research into Entity Framework (targeting DNX 4.5.1) I keep coming to the same conclusion that when using the code-first approach EF is supposed to create any tables that do not exist.

DbContext:

```
public class AccountReadContext : DbContext
    {
        public AccountReadContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
        {}

        public DbSet<AccountRead> AccountReads { get; set; }  
    }
```

Database Provider:

```
public void AddAccountRead(AccountRead reads)
        {
            _dbContext.AccountReads.Add(reads);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges(); //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AccountRead'
        }
```

I know *why* this is happening (the table is missing).  What I can't figure out is how do I get code-first to do its thing and create the table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581147/entity-framework-exception-invalid-object-name

Comment: @Think2ceCode1ce - I followed the linked advice and renamed my database (so it doesn't exist) but I just get `SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to use the EntityFramework commands in the project's root folder:

```
Update database:
dnx ef database update -c "AccountReadContext"

Add / Remove columns (specify column name):
dnx ef migrations add Reading -c "AccountReadContext"
dnx ef database update -c "AccountReadContext"
```

[This provides a bit more info](http://www.bricelam.net/2014/09/14/migrations-on-k.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable code first migrations in your project. In the PowerShell window (package manage console) you issue the command:

> Enable-Migrations

And then, every time you update your POCO objects, add new tables etc, you need to enter :

> Add-Migration

Some documentation on this here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.At line:1 char:1

Comment: Hmm, that should work, are you using Visual Studio, did you type that into package manager console? And do check that the correct project is selected before you hit enter :)

Comment: Yes checked all of those, I'm starting tho think I don't have EF correctly installed

Answer (score 0):

Automatic Migrations should be enabled by default. If you disabled them (AutomaticMigrations = false), you should run **Update-Database** command manually, or set the Database Initializer to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<,>